# How to split a string by slash in ruby

Tags: ruby, split

how can i split a string "DESKTOP-AHDESI\Username" by slash in ruby 2.7.1p83

```
tmp = "DESKTOP-AHDESI\Username"
print tmp

tmp = tmp.split("\\")
print tmp
```

[image]

**i got:**
Ruby Error: NoMethodError undefined method `gsub!'

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The error message you quoted *cannot possibly* be generated by the code you showed, since there is no call to `gsub!` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Your *tmp* variable is enclosed in double-quotes, and contains a backslash which is being interpreted as an escape rather than a character literal. You can see this easily by simply pasting your string into a REPL like irb:

```
"DESKTOP-AHDESI\Username" #=> "DESKTOP-AHDESIUsername"
```

You need to handle the backslash specially in both your String methods.

### Solution

One way to handle this is to use Ruby's alternate quoting mechanism. For example:

```
%q(DESKTOP-AHDESI\Username).split '\\'   #=> ["DESKTOP-AHDESI", "Username"]
```

This may not help you directly, though.
Wherever the value from *tmp* is coming from, you need to refactor the code to ensure that your String is properly escaped *before* you assign it to your variable, or otherwise pre-process it. [String#dump](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-dump) won't really help much if the value you're assigning is unescaped before assignment, so you're going to have to fix this in whatever code you're using to generate or grab the string in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are giving the wrong string. `\` is the escape character when you use inside the `""`. So It will try to escape the next character U but this character doesn't have any Job so it will print U on the screen. Modify your string like below, it will work.

```
tmp = "DESKTOP-AHDESI\\Username"
p tmp

tmp = tmp.split("\\")
p tmp
```

Output

```
"DESKTOP-AHDESI\\Username"
["DESKTOP-AHDESI", "Username"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but my string always contains one slash:
"DESKTOP-AHDESI\Username"

Comment: No, it does not. That string does *not* contain a backslash. The backslash in a string literal is an *escape character*, meaning it gives the next character a special meaning. However, `U` does not have any special meaning, which means that there is no need to escape it, and thus the backslash simply is ignored. The string you posted is exactly the same as `"DESKTOP-AHDESIUsername"`. Why don't you just print it and try it out?

Comment: To illustrate @JörgWMittag 's comment: `p "I\U".size` returns 2.